# How can I separate a string with lines in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a program which spellchecks the input words from a text file and then adds asterisks around the words with typos. The input is like this:

```
The quick brown fox

jumps over the lazy dog

and mispells someting
```

However, the print in the end looks like this:

```
*The* quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and *mispells* *someting*
```

How can I add the "\n" in the right places? The code is here:

```
def main():
    lahtotiedosto = open("words.txt", "r")
    list = []
    input_list = []
    for rivi in lahtotiedosto:
        rivi = rivi.rstrip()
        list.append(rivi)

    print("Enter the text to be spell-checked (empty line to end input).")
    typos = 0
    syote = input()
    while syote != "":
        input_list.append(syote)
        syote = input()
    new_list = []
    for syote in input_list:
        sanat = syote.split(" ")
        for i in sanat:
            if i in list:
                uusi_lista.append(i)
            else:
                i = "*{:}*".format(i)
                new_list.append(i)
                typos += 1

    print("Checked text, typos highlighted with '*'")
    ready_list = ' '.join(new_list)
    print(ready_list)
    print("There were", typos, "typos.")

main()
```

Comment: Your code is eliminating the line breaks because it splits each line into words and then assembles a list of those words. So it is not preserving the line breaks in the input. Try `sanat = syote.split(" ") + ["\n"]`. But you will also have to make an exception for this so that it is not marked as an error.

Comment: Take a look at `str.splitlines(True)` which will split the string into a list, retaining the newline. Then you will need to traverse each element in the list allowing for a newline at the end, with the possible exception of the last item.

Comment: the list approach is quite tricky since to recover the multi-line string you need first the keep in mind the original positions of the line-breaks and then update them with the amount of misspell per line. If you are note subject to any restrictions use regular expressions!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `'\n'` when joining the list elements:

```
ready_list = '\n'.join(new_list)
```

This separates each string in the list with the newline-command.

Comment: Thanks, but the \n should be in the exact place where it is in the original input, i.e. after "fox" and "dog", not after each word.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
ready_list = ' '.join(new_list)
```

to

```
ready_list = '\n'.join(new_list)
```

Comment: That puts every word in the output on a new line. It seems to me OP wants to preserve the line breaks in the input, not add new ones.

Comment: Thanks, but the \n should be in the exact place where it is in the original input, i.e. after "fox" and "dog", not after each word.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```py
print(*ready_list,sep='\n')
```

It will print each element in the list.

Comment: Thanks, but the \n should be in the exact place where it is in the original input, i.e. after "fox" and "dog", not after each word.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add `'\n'` in `ready_list = ' '.join(new_list)`

From:
`ready_list = ' '.join(new_list)`

To:
`ready_list = '\n'.join(new_list)`

Comment: Thanks, but the \n should be in the exact place where it is in the original input, i.e. after "fox" and "dog", not after each word.